# Trouble with Fragments in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am trying to make a fragment Java file. The xml fragment name is firstscreenlayout. This is the code.

```
public class FirstScreenFrag extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstscreenlayout, container, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

The line `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstscreenlayout, container, false);` is underlined and says unreachable statement when hovered over. I don't know how to fix this.

I am very new to coding, but am learning in my free time as a student. Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove below line

```
 return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

You  can return either your inflated view or do super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

return  only one of them depending upon your requirement

Answer (score 0):

return means your method finished, and the code will not execute after return.
try to remove this.

```
return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```